# sed search and replace with 2 conditions/patterns

Tags: sed

I have a file:

```
<a href="http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/">http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/</a>
<a href="../../3/glob.html" rel="nofollow">glob</a>
<a href="lxc-ls.html" rel="nofollow">lxc-ls</a>
```

I need to only replace below:

```
<a href="lxc-ls.html" rel="nofollow">lxc-ls</a>
```

with

```
<a href="../lxc-ls.html" rel="nofollow">lxc-ls</a>
```

**lxc-ls** can be any word as I have multiple such links in several files which I need to replace.

I do not want to make any changes to the other 2 links. i.e.

```
<a href="http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/">http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/</a>
<a href="../../3/glob.html" rel="nofollow">glob</a>
```

What I have tried until is:

```
$ sed '/html/ i\
..' file
```

But this appends to the start of the line, also the other condition of excluding 2 URLs is also not full filled.

Here is a more realistic example from one of the file.

```
<b><a href="../../1/echoping.html" rel="nofollow">echoping</a></b>(1),
<b><a href="../../3/getaddrinfo.html" rel="nofollow">getaddrinfo</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../3/getaddrinfo_a.html" rel="nofollow">getaddrinfo_a</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../2/getpeername.html" rel="nofollow">getpeername</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="../../2/getsockname.html" rel="nofollow">getsockname</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="../../3/ping_setopt.html" rel="nofollow">ping_setopt</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../5/proc.html" rel="nofollow">proc</a></b>(5),
<b><a href="rds.html" rel="nofollow">rds</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../../2/recv.html" rel="nofollow">recv</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="rtnetlink.html" rel="nofollow">rtnetlink</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="sctp.html" rel="nofollow">sctp</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../../3/sctp_connectx.html" rel="nofollow">sctp_connectx</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../2/send.html" rel="nofollow">send</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="udplite.html" rel="nofollow">udplite</a></b>(7)
<a href="http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html">http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html</a>
<a href="http://translationproject.org/team/">http://translationproject.org/team/</a>
```

Here I only need to replace:

```
<b><a href="rds.html" rel="nofollow">rds</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="rtnetlink.html" rel="nofollow">rtnetlink</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="sctp.html" rel="nofollow">sctp</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="udplite.html" rel="nofollow">udplite</a></b>(7)
```

with:

```
<b><a href="../rds.html" rel="nofollow">rds</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../rtnetlink.html" rel="nofollow">rtnetlink</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../sctp.html" rel="nofollow">sctp</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../udplite.html" rel="nofollow">udplite</a></b>(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'|"\([[:alpha:]].*\)|"../\1|' file
<b><a href="../../1/echoping.html" rel="../nofollow">echoping</a></b>(1),
<b><a href="../../3/getaddrinfo.html" rel="../nofollow">getaddrinfo</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../3/getaddrinfo_a.html" rel="../nofollow">getaddrinfo_a</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../2/getpeername.html" rel="../nofollow">getpeername</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="../../2/getsockname.html" rel="../nofollow">getsockname</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="../../3/ping_setopt.html" rel="../nofollow">ping_setopt</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../5/proc.html" rel="../nofollow">proc</a></b>(5),
<b><a href="../rds.html" rel="nofollow">rds</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../../2/recv.html" rel="../nofollow">recv</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="../rtnetlink.html" rel="nofollow">rtnetlink</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../sctp.html" rel="nofollow">sctp</a></b>(7),
<b><a href="../../3/sctp_connectx.html" rel="../nofollow">sctp_connectx</a></b>(3),
<b><a href="../../2/send.html" rel="../nofollow">send</a></b>(2),
<b><a href="../udplite.html" rel="nofollow">udplite</a></b>(7)
```

Comment: Ohh my bad. I did not mention that "lxc-ls" can be anything. So we can not really search it directly using sed. I will edit the main question as well.

Comment: I have multiple urls like this ```<a href="rand01.html" rel="nofollow">lxc-ls</a>``` ```<a href="rand02.html" rel="nofollow">lxc-ls</a>``` etc... So I really dont know what word will appear in ```href="xxxxx.html``` portion of the link.

Comment: added an example with more links. basically I want to add a relative path to all the local html file and exclude links which are already with relative path or with absolute path like ```href="../.."``` or ```href="../"``` or ```href="google.com"```

Comment: It almost worked. But the only problem is that it also adds ```../``` to the links such as ```href="www.google.com"``` How can we exclude these as well. Thanks for your answer though. It is close to wat I want. I have also added the sample extra links to my original question. If you can please try your code.

Comment: maybe if there is any way to ask sed to ignore such lines which contain "www" or "*.com" or "http"

Comment: @Sandeep_Patil `sed '/"http\|"www/ ! s|"\([[:alpha:]].*\)|"../\1|' file`